# gtk+3 programme compilelation in codeblocks showing fatal error

Tags: code-blocks

I have tried to compile a c programe with gtk+3 in code blocks but its showing

> ```
> fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory|
> ```

Comment: Post the compile flags.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install necessary development package with:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev libgtk-3-dev
```

as it contains [needed headers](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=gtk%2Fgtk.h).

Comment: libgtk-3-dev is already the newest version (3.24.18-1ubuntu1).